# Flatten nested array of objects prepending parent value to child

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have a nested array of objects and want to get only the child property elements of an array with the **title of the parent element prepended to the title in the child**. This is just an example and the actual data will include a unique children property in separate indices in the array.

I would like to implement flatMap in my solution instead of using flattenDeep and map from lodash. Please advice.

```js
const headers = [{
  "id": "name1",
  "title": "Name 1",
  "children": [{
    "title": "Children 1",
    "child": [{
      "title": "Child 1",
      "onClick": "child1Click"
    }, {
      "title": "Child 2",
      "onClick": "child2Click"
    }]
  }, {
    "title": "CHildren 2",
    "child": [{
      "title": "Child 3",
      "id": "child3Click"
    }, {
      "title": "Child 4",
      "id": "child4Click"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "id": "name2",
  "title": "Name 2",
  "children": [{
    "title": "Children 3",
    "child": [{
      "title": "Child 5",
      "onClick": "child5Click"
    }, {
      "title": "Child 6",
      "onClick": "child6Click"
    }]
  }, {
    "title": "CHildren 4",
    "child": [{
      "title": "Child 7",
      "id": "child7Click"
    }, {
      "title": "Child 8",
      "id": "child8Click"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "id": "name3",
  "title": "Name 3"
}, {
  "id": "name4",
  "title": "Name 4"
}]

console.log(_.flattenDeep(_.map(_.flattenDeep(_.compact(_.map(headers, item => item.children))), item => _.map(item.child, child => {
 return {
   ...child,
    title: `${item.title} ${child.title}`
  }
}))))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The output I expect is

```
[
  {
    "title": "Children 1 Child 1",
    "onClick": "child1Click"
  },
  {
    "title": "Children 1 Child 2",
    "onClick": "child2Click"
  },
  {
    "title": "CHildren 2 Child 3",
    "id": "child3Click"
  },
  {
    "title": "CHildren 2 Child 4",
    "id": "child4Click"
  },
  {
    "title": "Children 3 Child 5",
    "onClick": "child5Click"
  },
  {
    "title": "Children 3 Child 6",
    "onClick": "child6Click"
  },
  {
    "title": "CHildren 4 Child 7",
    "id": "child7Click"
  },
  {
    "title": "CHildren 4 Child 8",
    "id": "child8Click"
  }
]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I have the output. I just need an extra pair of eyes to get me an optimal one.

Comment: optimal from which perspective?

Comment: A better way to get the output? I have been wanting to use flatMap from lodash but not sure how to end up using it as opposed to map and flattenDeep

Comment: "A better way" is not well defined, you need to state what is your criteria to assess something as "better". Cleaner code? code that is more testable? more concise? easier to maintain and modify? more performant? more to your personal taste? requires less polyfills? ...

Comment: Sorry Alfasin.. i’m not that clear maybe..

Comment: No worries, take your time and improve the question so that people will be able to help you!

Comment: Do you have only 2 levels of children depth like in your example?

Comment: Yes, the first level is children and second is child. Child is the innermost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this with just `reduce` and two inner `forEach` loops for children and child.

```js
const headers = [{"id":"name1","title":"Name 1","children":[{"title":"Children 1","child":[{"title":"Child 1","onClick":"child1Click"},{"title":"Child 2","onClick":"child2Click"}]},{"title":"CHildren 2","child":[{"title":"Child 3","id":"child3Click"},{"title":"Child 4","id":"child4Click"}]}]},{"id":"name2","title":"Name 2","children":[{"title":"Children 3","child":[{"title":"Child 5","onClick":"child5Click"},{"title":"Child 6","onClick":"child6Click"}]},{"title":"CHildren 4","child":[{"title":"Child 7","id":"child7Click"},{"title":"Child 8","id":"child8Click"}]}]},{"id":"name3","title":"Name 3"},{"id":"name4","title":"Name 4"}]

const result = headers.reduce((r, {children}) => {
  children && children.forEach(({title: pTitle, child}) => {
    child && child.forEach(({title, ...rest}) => r.push({
      title: `${pTitle} ${title}`,
      ...rest
    }))
  })
  
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a way to extend this function to prepend the title? _.flatMap(_.compact(_.flatMap(headers, 'children')), 'child')

Comment: There could be some specific method for this exact scenario in lodash but basically what you did https://jsfiddle.net/qmvc10hr/